# MySQL : Don't select duplicate row item when one of them has status = 1

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates, exists

have a table with duplicate data, I'm able to group email by using this query

```
SELECT id, first_name, email, status FROM customers WHERE status = '0' GROUP BY email
```

However, I don't want to select customer with duplicate emails that already have the status = '1'

Table design as follows...

```
id   first_name  email              status
1    Tony        tony@gmail.com       0
2    Terry       terry@gmail.com      0
3    Alex        alex@gmail.com       0
4    John        john@gmail.com       0
5    Mike        mike@gmail.com       1
6    Mike Jones  mike@gmail.com       0
7    Mike Fake   mike@gmail.com       0
```

my query still selects mike@gmail.com because there are status with 0 but in fact, there's one already with the status=1.... How do I not select the email that already have the status=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Using **LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.email, c.status 
FROM customers c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c1 ON c.email = c1.email AND c1.cstatus = 1
WHERE c.status = 0 AND c1.id IS NULL
GROUP BY c.email;
```

Using **NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.email, c.status 
FROM customers c 
WHERE c.status = 0 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customers c1 WHERE c.email = c1.email AND c1.cstatus = 1)
GROUP BY c.email;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be using `not exists`

```
select c.* from customers c where not exists
(
  select 1 from customers c1
  where c1.email = c.email
  and c1.status = 1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, first_name, email, status, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '0' THEN 1 END) AS zero_status_count
COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 END) AS one_status_count
FROM customers GROUP BY email having zero_status_count > 0 and one_status_count < 1;
```

try this.